# Can I use Xamarin to develop windows and mac application in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, macos, xamarin

I have never worked with mac operating system. I want to develop an application which can run on Mac and Windows, can I use Xamarin to develop the application?

What does Xamarin.Forms does?

I have search on the web but couldn't find an answer. Please help!

Comment: I have installed Xamarinstudio and it doesn't have any Forms template. I did know Xamarin is  different from XamarinStudio.

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://github.com/picoe/Eto or https://github.com/mono/xwt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Xamarin Forms](http://xamarin.com/forms):**

> "Build native UIs for iOS, Android and Windows Phone from a single,
>   shared C# codebase"

You can still implement Mac and Windows using Xamarin using the same ***Portable class library***. You just need to build your own UI for Mac and Windows.

More Info on portable class libraries: [Cross-Platform Development with the Portable Class Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin.Forms has been updated since the question was asked so I thought I add the following:

Using Xamarin.Forms, you can now create cross-platform apps that target the following platforms all using the same code:

**UWP**

This is ideal for creating apps for Windows 10 and if you plan to distribute them either through the Store or by sideloading. It's fast but lacks a lot of APIs and features and seems like Microsoft has a lot of work to do.

**WPF**

Yes, using XF you can build for WPF as well but it's still in preview (at the time of writing) so a lot of things don't work yet (for example ListView Headers)

**iOS**

Build native apps for iPhone, iPad and iPod

**Android**

Build native apps for devices running Android

**macOS**

The same app can also run on macOS but it is still in preview (at the time of writing)

**Tizen**

It is now possible to build for smartphones, watches and TVs running Samsung Tizen using XF.

**Linux**

How nice it is that I can run the same Windows/iOS/macOS/Android app on Linux too! I have not tested it personally myself yet

**Conclusion:**

Using Xamarin.Forms you can target many platforms at the same time using the same code and if you need to access platform-specific features you can still do that (for example by DependencyService)